# Simplify Sum of Products: $\;A'B'C' + A'B'C + ABC'$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How would you simplify the following sum of products expression using algebraic manipulations in boolean algebra?

$$A'B'C' + A'B'C + ABC'$$

Comment: You have to say a bit about what each letter represents. Matrices?

Comment: Its boolean algebra

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28NOT+A+AND+NOT+B+AND+NOT+C%29+OR+%28NOT+A+AND+NOT+B+AND+C%29+OR+%28A+AND+B+AND+NOT+C%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, all that's involved here is using the distributive law (DL), once.

Distributive Law, multiplication over addition: $$PQ + PR = P(Q + R)\tag{DL}$$

In your expression, in the first two terms, put $P = A'B'$:

We also use the identity $$\;P + P' = 1\tag{+ID}$$

---

$$\begin{align} A'B'C' + A'B'C + ABC' & = A'B'(C' + C) + ABC' \tag{DL}\\ \\ &= A'B'(1) + ABC' \tag{+ ID}\\ \\ & = A'B' + ABC'\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the first two terms are the same except for the $C'$ or $C$.  Put those two terms together.

Comment: So A'B' + ABC' ?